# How to play a random video from a list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video, youtube

I have a list of videos in an array and I want to be able to make the player play another video from the list after the current one ends. The problem I'm having is that it repeats the same video once its ends instead of selecting a new video to play. I've been looking for similar questions and havent been able to find anything to make it work. Any advice would be appreciated!

```
var tag = document.createElement('script');

tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

// 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
// after the API code downloads.
function rotateYT() {
    var videos = [
        'be0T_owA1PU',
        'Kp7eSUU9oy8',
        'Th0V-fxo9CE',
    ];

    var index=Math.floor(Math.random() * videos.length);
    return videos[index];
}

var player;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    var videoID = rotateYT();
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
        height: '300',
        width: '300',
        videoId: videoID,
        events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
        }
    });
}

// 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
function onPlayerReady(event) {
    player.setPlaybackRate(1);
    event.target.playVideo();
}

// 5. This should play another random video
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {        
    if(event.data === 0) {
        event.target.setShuffle(true); 
        event.target.playVideo();
    }
}
```

I probably put the code in wrong so here is the jsfiddle ive been working on

https://jsfiddle.net/bbasham/L20k7x1o/2/

Comment: What is issue with `javascript` at Question?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you are not telling the YT player to use a playlist of videos. Instead, you are only setting one video ID at a time, therefore, the `shuffle` method would not work. You need to update your method so that you swap the video ID before restarting:

```
// 5. This should play another random video
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {        
    if(event.data === 0) {
        //event.target.setShuffle(true); //useless unless the player has a playlist
        event.target.loadVideoById( rotateYT() ); 
        event.target.playVideo();
    }
}
```

That will cause the player to grab a new video and set it as the source before restarting the player. Alternatively you could provide a playlist and then use shuffle.

[Documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#loadVideoById)

Comment: Thanks for the response. If I provided a playlist and added more videos to the playlist would the code be able to grab the new videos or would I have to update the code every time I add a video?

Ultimately I wanted to be able to create a playlist of videos and have it grab randoms ones, I just didn't know if this was the best way or not.